# get-spmanagedaccount how to get the samaccountname and not sid

Tags: powershell, managed-account

When I do following i get `sid`. How do i get the account name (domain\svc-search) etc.

```
foreach($ma in get-spmanagedaccount)
{
    write-host $ma
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
foreach($ma in get-spmanagedaccount)
{ 
 write-host $ma.DisplayName
 write-host $ma.UserName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
foreach($ma in Get-SPManagedAccount){$ma.UserName}
```